# Nuxt: How to add content/scripts to the head dynamically on server side

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxt.js, head

How can I add dynamically content to the head in Nuxt on server side?

I was trying to rewrite this module here which supports only static id's: https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/blob/master/packages/google-tag-manager/index.js

(My id is coming from the store (The store is fetching the id from a rest call))

This is the function which is adding the content to the head:

```
export default function addheadcode(head, id) {
  const options = {
    id: id,
    layer: 'dataLayer',
    pageTracking: true,
    pageViewEventName: 'nuxtRoute',
    respectDoNotTrack: false,
    query: {},
    scriptURL: '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js',
    noscriptURL: '//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html',
    env: {} // env is supported for backward compability and is alias of query
  }

  const queryParams = Object.assign({}, options.env, options.query)

  queryParams.id = options.id

  if (options.layer) {
    queryParams.l = options.layer
  }

  const queryString = Object.keys(queryParams)
    .filter(key => queryParams[key] !== null && queryParams[key] !== undefined)
    .map(
      key =>
        `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(queryParams[key])}`
    )
    .join('&')

  head = head || {}
  head.noscript = head.noscript || []
  head.script = head.script || []

  head.script.push({
    hid: 'gtm',
    src:
      (options.scriptURL || '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js') +
      '?' +
      queryString,
    async: true
  })

  head.noscript.push({
    hid: 'gtm-noscript',
    innerHTML: `<iframe src="${options.noscriptURL}?${queryString}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
    pbody: true
  })

  head.__dangerouslyDisableSanitizersByTagID =
    head.__dangerouslyDisableSanitizersByTagID || {}
  head.__dangerouslyDisableSanitizersByTagID['gtm-noscript'] = ['innerHTML']
}
```

And this is my middleware which I am executing only on server side
**/middleware/gtm.js**

```
import gtmAddheadcode from '~/src/googletagmanager.js'

export default function({ store, app }) {
  if (process.server) {
    const gtmID = store.getters['websiteskeleton/googelTagManagerId']
    gtmAddheadcode(app.head, gtmID)
  }
}
```

**Problem:**
On the first call it seems to work fine. Here is the output which I can see on client side:

```
<script data-n-head="true" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-P4FZ3XX&amp;l=dataLayer" async="true"></script><noscript data-n-head="true" data-hid="gtm-noscript" pbody="true"><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXX&l=dataLayer" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

If I refresh that page. I see the same content double. If i refresh it again I see it threefold.

1) Why is Nuxt saving this state of the application?

2) What can I do to fix this problem?

EDIT:
I created a git repository with the code. The problem occurs only in production mode! You can't see it while running dev.
[Example repository](https://github.com/sowinski/nuxtheadbug)

EDIT 2:
It is a bug an will be fixed: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6786#event-2893743506

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1.

This does indeed sound like a bug somewhere.  Nuxt should not be saving state like this across requests.  This seems like a huge issue to me, making it incredibly easy to cause memory leaks in your app by just omitting the `hid`.  I would suggest opening an issue on the Nuxt github page addressing this.

My educated guess is that Nuxt might persist the state of `vue-meta`, the library that's used to work with the `head` tag, and assumes that users will be using `hid` on their elements to replace them when needed.

2.

The only suggestion I have is to add `hid` to your script object, naming it something common like 'gtag'.

```
  head.script.push({
    hid: 'gtag',
    src:
      (options.scriptURL || '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js') +
      '?' +
      queryString,
    async: true
  })
```

Comment: Adding hid did not help. But I think the October release have fixed this issue: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/release-notes#v2.10.1 I build a small sandbox with the newest version of nuxt and the bug is not there anymore. I will try to update my application and give an update here.

Comment: I've taken the newest release and I have the same problem. You can only see the behavior on production (npm run start) and not on dev (npm run dev). Any idea?

Comment: The first thing I would do is console.log the head.script array to see if that's where the duplication is taking place.  You may just be able to filter out the old one before adding the new gtag.

Comment: I just do a "head.script = []" and reset it on my own on every request and it seems to work. I also reported this bug to nuxt. Let's see if this is a feature or bug.